# set up paperclip with amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up the paperclip with amazon s3, I have found a tutorial which is like the following code. What do I have to put as a url and path ?

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
 :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
 :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
 :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
},
:url => ':s3_domain_url',
:path => "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about touching url, unless you care about whether or not the URL is placed domain-style (bucket-name.s3.amazonaws) or path-style (s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name). You could not add that in your configurations and it will default to domain-style.

Path tells Paperclip what path to save your attachments. This means in local file system, it will save it under "(model's name)/(attachment name)/(id)/(style e.g. small, thumbnail)/(file name)." It will do the same thing for your bucket, so you'll have all these fun folders to click through if you view your physical bucket. You're free to leave it to the default, or change it if you want your path to be a little shorter.